# Python not finding module for personal class

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, module, set

I'm having a module issue with a custom class I wrote for calulating fuzzy sets. All of my files are in the same directory and this driver (attached) will access the fuzzyelements.py class but not the fuzzyset.py. All three are in the same directory like I said before, but python can't locate the add_element() method I call on line 21 from fuzzyset.py. Does anyone know why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9N8U.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. You seem to be expecting a module to have this method instead of a class.

Comment: You meant to write: ‘F.addElement(alice1)’

Answer (score 0):

I think your `class name` and your `file name` should not be the same.
Change your file name, for example, `fuzzysetutility.py.`

and import a class like

```
from fuzzysetutility import fuzzyset
```

Comment: I quite agree with you. Unfortunately python itself has examples of this practice.